# State is modified before state setter is called

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, antd

I have a form with a single input that takes some value, sends a request to the backend to create a new entity and updates the frontend by adding the new value to the collection of items.

Handler which gets executed on form submit:

```
const handleItemInsert = async (item: any): Promise<void> => {
    console.log('BEFORE ITEM CREATE', items);

    const newItem: IItem = await service.addNewItemAsync(item);

    console.log('AFTER ITEM ADD', items);
    console.log(newItem);

    setItems((items) => [...items, newItem]);
}
```

My issue is that the **first time** I add a new item the state is somehow modified(the `newItem` is added to the `items` collection) before even the service gets called. Furthermore, the new item gets added twice and I am not sure why. Every related function that I've checked is called once and I have this problem with and without using `StrictMode`, so the issue shouldn't be based on that.

[Here is a full Codesandbox sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-lake-9tzzc?file=/src/App.tsx) of the issue.

I've put logs in the function calls that reflect the problem in the flow(you can check them in the codesandbox console window). I might be missing something really trivial but at this point I really don't see where the error lies.

Also, if the problem lies in the handling of the form submit itself through **antd**'s `onFinish` method(as I am passing an async method), it should still execute update logic after the logs and don't add the item twice.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your service is mutating `ITEMS` and you set that value to the state, you are inadvertently modifying React's state.

Update you effect to create a shallow copy of items when you set them:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchItems() {
      console.log("FETCH ITEMS CALLED.");

      const items = await service.getAllItemsAsync();

      console.log("INITIAL ITEMS", items);

      setItems([...items]);
    }

    fetchItems();
  }, []);
```

[image: Edit compassionate-dhawan-o8h73]

Comment: Migrated from a real to a mock service and I've missed to return a copy of the data instead of the actual object in the service itself. Thank you very much!